# How to get value after DB select and DB raw in laravel

Tags: laravel

How can i get the string after call this DB function in laravel?

```
DB::select(DB::raw('select uuid_short()'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shorter way could be;

```
DB::selectOne(DB::raw('select uuid_short() as uuid'))->uuid
```

Other one;

```
DB::select(DB::raw('select uuid_short() as uuid'))[0]->uuid
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
DB::select(DB::raw('select uuid_short() as uuid'))[0]->uuid
```